# Issue cloning SSD to larger SSD

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, ssd, disk-cloning

I have recently purchased a new SSD which I am trying to set as my primary drive for my OS. Currently my original drive (C:/) is also an SSD however space is becoming an issue (its only 60GB) while the new one is 240GB in size (F:/).

I cloned the disk using Intel Data Migration utility since both of the drives are Intel drives. However when I attempt to boot from the new drive I get an error saying that the boot manager is missing.

Here is the current disk set-up
[image: Current Disk Set-up]

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put boot files on first disk (disk 0) on admin command prompt:

```
bcdboot f:\windows /s f:
```

Assuming first disk (disk 0) was formatted using Windows 7/8/10. The MBR (master boot record) should contain Windows 7/8/10 boot code.

As bootsect.exe utility is not present in Windows 7 system directory by default you could download and use [Dual-boot Repair tool](http://dual-boot-repair-windows-10.html) for writing Windows MBR to first disk (disk 0).

Comment: Why does the author need a third-party tool to solve this if `bcdboot` will solve it?  Why link to what is obviously a website most wouldn't consider to be legitimate, nor does it work, but that is a separate concern.

Comment: @Ramhound - what exactly does not work?

Comment: @snayob ok, I have managed to boot to the new disk, so thanks! :) one other thing though, if I format my C:/ will this cause problems (e.g. with application settings or game saves), ideally I would change the drive letters but I do not know if this will cause problems?

Comment: @MatthewPigram, glad I could help and problem solved. To experiment if formatting c: would cause problems for application or game settings you can hide drive using Disk Management when in other OS.

Comment: if I hide the disk can I change over the drive letter? Ideally I would like to have the new drive as the C:\ drive and format the other to become just a regular storage drive.

Comment: You can use Disk Management to change non-OS drive letters. To change drive letter of OS - "How to restore the system/boot drive letter in Windows" - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/223188